# Non-standard evaluation for setting one input based on the value of another

Tags: r

Can non-standard evaluation be used to accomplish the following?

```
rnorm( 10, mean = 2, sd = mean/2 )
```

This pseudocode intends to set `sd`  to half of `mean`. Is there a way to set an input based on the values of other inputs to its left?

Hadley Wickham has a chapter in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)
 about NSE, but I haven't found a similar principle there or on SO. A negative answer would also be helpful.

I've found one example of a function that does something similar within the `dplyr` package:

```
mutate(my_df, x = a + b, y = x + c)
```

A new variable `x` is defined as the sum of existing variables `a` and `b`. Then, a new variable `y` is defined as the sum of the newly created `x` and an already existing `c`.

Comment: Is it an option for you to simply create a custom function to do this? (processing input arguments and then calling rnorm for example)

Comment: Yes, I could definitely do that. But I'm really curious to know if something like the above is possible.

Comment: From my understanding, it is not possible in the current setup as "mean" is the name of an argument. It has some meaning within the `rnorm` function, but a different interpretation outside (it is a function). As mentioned you could build your own function or you could define a single variable (for example, myMean) and define the variables in `rnorm` based on this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback